# Shifting Strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to programming and have been a bit shy when it comes to asking for help....to be honest, I get intimidated by how fast others can figure something out, so for those of you that are in the category, I was hoping you could help me out with a homework question. I Don't know where to begin or write the pseudocode, but if you can guide me or give me a response with details of the why and how, I'd owe you a huge debt. Here's the problem:

we define the following operations on a string:

left shifts: a single circular rotation of the string in which the first character becomes the last 
character and all other characters are shifted one index to the left. For example, bcdea becomes 
cdeab after a left shift.

right shifts: same as above but in reverse, the last character becomes the first.

the following parameters:
s: string to shift
left shift: integer
right shift: integer

constraints:

> 1 <= s <= 10^5
>   0 <= leftshifts, rightshifts <= 10^9

```
function getShiftedString(s, leftShifts, rightShifts) {
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+shifting+strings - Should be where you always start. Read the things and if you have trouble understanding one of those things you ask questions about "that thing". Simply posting your homework question and asking someone to solve it is not the way to go

Comment: So, I know that we're going to iterate and use a for loop, create a new array for the left shift and right shift, but i'm still confused as to how to go about it.

Comment: Use JS substring method – https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp. I am not sure about you constraints meaning.

Answer (score 4):

```
function getShiftedString(s, leftShifts, rightShifts) {
    s = leftShifting(s, leftShifts);
    return rightShifting(s,  rightShifts);
}

function leftShifting(s, leftShifts) {
    return s.substring(leftShifts) + s.substring(0, leftShifts);
}

function rightShifting(s,  rightShifts) {
    let l = s.length - rightShifts;
    return leftShifting(s, l);
}
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it out in psudo code, that'll help you plan your function.

Think about what you need this function to do, you need it to:
accept a string
shift it to the right x number of times,
shift it to the left y number of times

so maybe your psudo code would look a little like this

```
s = string, x = left, y = right
convert s to array
for (x times)
  q = first element in array
  remove first element from array
  add q to end of array

for (y times)
  q = last element in array
  remove last element from array
  add q to the beginning of the array

make s string again
return s
```

Then it's just a simple matter of converting that to code.

Keep in mind, that's just one solution, and there are far better ones out there. definitely do what Neil Lunn said though, and look up string shifting.

Comment: am I going to do two for loops?

Comment: It's one way to do it. If you think about the problem, you might be able to find a more innovative way to do it.

Comment: If the answer helped you, would you mind making it the accepted answer?

Comment: I’m still confused as to the “for x times” how would I write that out in code?

Comment: Let s = str.split(‘’) let x= right let y = left. How do I add integers in there then do the steps to count either right or left?

Comment: I know you helped me out with the pseudo code, but can you help me line by line in code with an explanation. This one question is the only question I’m trying to really figure out.